# Latex graphs into a subcaption grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption

I am wondering if it is possible to arrange latex graphs into a grid.

I know it is possible to arrange graphics using the subcaption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A mouse}\label{fig:mouse}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A gull}\label{fig:gull}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{A tiger}\label{fig:tiger}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Picture of animals}
\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However my graphs are in the format of

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{tables/txy/fine/vel/p1.csv}\txyone

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    title={location pos 1 inlet x},
    scale only axis,
    legend pos = outer north east,
    xlabel=U (m/s), 
    ylabel=Y/S (inches),
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 12,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 10,
    x dir=reverse,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=blue, smooth] table[x = x1, y = y2]{\txyone};
    \legend{Laminar, k-$\epsilon$ realizable, k-$\omega$, SST, RSM,}
    \legend{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{initial inlet x dir}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried replacing the `\includegraphics[]{}` with the code of the graph, however this did not work

Is there any way of inserting a tikzpicture graph as a sub caption grid?

Comment: if you want help with an error it's best to make a complete document that can be run to reproduce the error. I don't see any reason why you should not be able to replace `\includegraphics` by a `tikzpicture`

Comment: I will update with error

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working. If anyone else has the same problem, heres the format i used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{tables/txy/fine/vel/p1.csv}\txyone

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [

    ]
    \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=blue, smooth] table[x = x1, y = y2]{\txyone};
    \legend{Laminar, k-$\epsilon$ realizable, k-$\omega$, SST, RSM,}
    \legend{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [

    ]
    \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=blue, smooth] table[x = x1, y = y2]{\txyone};
    \legend{Laminar, k-$\epsilon$ realizable, k-$\omega$, SST, RSM,}
    \legend{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [

    ]
    \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=blue, smooth] table[x = x1, y = y2]{\txyone};
    \legend{Laminar, k-$\epsilon$ realizable, k-$\omega$, SST, RSM,}
    \legend{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [

    ]
    \addplot[domain=1:1e4,color=blue, smooth] table[x = x1, y = y2]{\txyone};
    \legend{Laminar, k-$\epsilon$ realizable, k-$\omega$, SST, RSM,}
    \legend{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```